# WooCommerce CSV Image URL Creates Additional Images in Media Folder

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, media-library

I upload all images through the Media Library Drag and Drop Uploader with no problems.
Every time I use a CSV file with several thousand products, I enter the image url for each product, which is located in the Media Library.
Example: /wp-content/uploads/2018/08/oa901-essence-1oz.jpg

As a result, the product page uses the image with the added -1 instead of the original or even a thumbnail of the original.
Then when I download all of the products, the image url has the added -1 to the end of the image file name.
I can't figure out why this is happening and how to fix it.
I tried deactivating almost every plugin, even manually uploading single products, but it still does the same thing.
I can't use the images with the added -1, or -2, or -3, or -4, because those images do not display in the Media Library.
Any Ideas?

Attached are some screen shots.
[image: Replicated Images On The Server]
[image: Replicated Images In The Media Library]
[image: Wrong Image Chosen With the Added -1]

Comment: I think you may need to break down your process in more detail - step by step - as it's not really clear at least to me what you're doing, or how the product page is producing its links. As for the images themselves, for some reason, the library thinks you've already uploaded essence-1oz.jpg, so, in order to avoid overwriting it when you upload again, it's adding "-1" to it

Comment: That is what I thought at first, but even when I blow out all of the images and product pages, re-upload the images and then import my product inventory CSV, I look into the Media Library and I can have up to 5 versions (-5) of the same file and thumbnails for each version. I uploaded 1800 images and then after the CSV import, it gets multiplied to 55K. On top of that, the product page always points to the -1 image instead of the original even though I have the original file path in the "image" column of the CSV. IDK

Comment: Well, I still don't understand exactly what you're doing, but, if I were in your position, and if I was unable through close scrutiny to see where images were being re-uploaded, I'd test to see if the same thing happens with one item, or several, or one hundred, etc. If it did, that would point in one direction - and a more easily de-buggable one. If it didn't, that would point in a different direction. Otherwise,if you can't specify exactly what you're doing, including the code and whatever other tools, at each step, then I don't think I can help you.

Comment: The additional images are being replicated after I import my CSV into WooCommerce. I have tested individual files, but same results. The only additional plugin I use is Product CSV Import Export (BASIC), everything else is default.

Comment: Still unsure here, but my guess is that the Imp/Ex plugin has an image field, and is set up to re-create product images from any provided image address. That they're not showing up in the media library looks like a possible flaw in the plugin. Or maybe it's intended to work that way. Can't say more without more details. If the plugin devs can't help, you may have to pay a developer to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload any image on media library Wp resize it in all thumb dimensions to have multiple dimensions of same image. For example on woocommerce shop page by default will be visible resized products featured images because of images weight. If full dimensions images e.g. 1200x1200 px would be displayed on a page with 36 products on a div with 300x300 dimensions that page would uselessly weight a lot consequently reducing page load speed.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are already uploaded to the WordPress Media, use the file names of the images instead of the full URL.

As mentioned in the WooCommerce [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-column-header-reference/)

> Enter the image URL or file name. The importer will look in
>   wp-content/uploads/year/month where year/month are the year and month
>   in which the import is run.